# Laravel 5.8 refresh database without losing data in tables already exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and each time I create a new migration I run `php artisan migrate:refresh` to update my database. I lose data stored in tables that already exist. I want to find a solution to add a new table without losing my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `php artisan migrate` (without `:refresh`), this only runs migrations that have not been run yet.

The idea with migrations is that you do not edit them after you run them.
More info on migrations can be found in the [migration documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding) too if you need some base data when you make a migration:refresh, please see the link to know more about that.